# C++ Poco client receiveResponse throw Poco::Net::NoMessageException

Tags: c++, post, httprequest, httpclient, poco

I'm doing some tests with POST HTTP request by using POCO, I get the response status 200 and reason OK, but when trying to receive the response I get the exception "Poco::Net::NoMessageException".

```
 //Uri for fake tests
    Poco::URI uri("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");

    Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());
    session.setKeepAlive(true);
    session.setTimeout(Poco::Timespan(20,0));


    std::string path(uri.getPathAndQuery());
    if(path.empty()) path = "/";

    Poco::Net::HTTPRequest request(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, path, Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);//request(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, path);

    request.setContentType("application/json");
        
    Poco::JSON::Object jsonObj;
    std::stringstream strStream;

    //Dummy data
    jsonObj.set("title", "Test product");
    jsonObj.set("price", "1520");
    jsonObj.set("category", "electronics");
    jsonObj.stringify(strStream);


    request.setContentLength(strStream.str().length());

    std::ostream& os = session.sendRequest(request);
    os << strStream.str();

    Poco::Net::HTTPResponse response;  
    std::cout << "Response status = " << response.getStatus() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Response Reason = " << response.getReason() << std::endl;   

    
    std::istream& inputStream = session.receiveResponse(response); //Hereis where the program fails
    std::cout << response.getContentLength() << std::endl;

    Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(inputStream, std::cout);
```

Output:

```
Response status = 200
Response Reason = OK
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Poco::Net::NoMessageException'
  what():  No message received

Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have tried to set the session keep alive to true and also with a timeout, but it doesn't seems to work.

The expected output should be

```
'{"_id":"61adc8ede087f30012c44053","id":21,"title":"test product","price":135,"category":"electronic"}'
```

Comment: You initialize `jsonObj` but never use it. You construct `response` without any explicit initialization and see it print `status = 200` and `reason = OK`, but these look like default-constructed values. Finally, your question does not satisfy the basic condition for a good question in SO: a decent [mre].